# 32 bit linux executable failing with Exec format error. Binary file not executable

Tags: c, linux

I built a 32 bit binary on linux 64 bit machine and trying to run.

It fails with error Exec format error. Binary file not executable.

```
./test

./test: Exec format error. Binary file not executable.



file test

test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b8710a266a084a5d6e8d63a585cc6824e382a5e6, not stripped
```

Machine details

```
uname -a

Linux den03cif 4.1.12-124.52.5.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Wed Jul 21 14:58:50 PDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: That's one old executable file. Where did you get it from? What is the program supposed to do? Do you have access to its source code? Can you rebuild it?

Comment: And have you installed a 32-bit environment to be able to run 32-bit applications?

Comment: Above test is part of my code. I have a few tests which run properly only one of them reports this error.

Comment: Would you mind to add the output of "file another_test"? Do you compile "test" differently than your other tests? What is the output of "ldd test"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure its because your machine architecture is x86_64 but you are trying to run something that was meant for i386 architecture

Comment: you can run i386 images on x86-64 without any problem, as long as the appropriate libs are installed

Comment: @phuclv Maybe he is missing the i386 library.

Comment: In case of missing libraries, the error should be different. I would rather imagine a binary file corruption (e.g. an ftp download in ascii mode).